# Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Query' not found

Tags: mongodb, yii

I am new in Yii framework and I am facing an issue with Yii and mongoDB. I have installed mongodb extension for PHP. I am using `php5.6` but I am getting an error

> Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Query' not found.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the file is there at `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Connection.php`.

Are there any differences in your main `composer.json` from what's in the application template you're using. Especially **extra, autoload**.
Make sure you're specifying version correctly or just try `*`. Verify `vendor/extensions.php` is ok and It should contain `yiisoft/yii2-mongo`.

Comment: I am having this issue. I do have the mongodb.so, its enabled on the php.ini, it is not showing on phpinfo(). The vendor files are there. Any idea?

Comment: @moplin can you check if your main `composer.json` has `"yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "*"` under `require` section, verify installation with `composer show -i ` and check if it is printed with the installed modules

Comment: Thanks my friend. It is "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.1.7", I do have the mongodb.so on the system and the "extension=mongodb.so" on php.ini, but Yii tells me that the Class is not found, and I cannot find mongo on the phpinfo() page. «I am on Ubuntu 10.04, xampp with php 7.1» and it driving me crazy.

Comment: does `php -v` on terminal shows you the version 7 ? and go through [**`this`**](https://gist.github.com/brutalenemy666/1023d78e67e54ba849a49d7abc9a3ca7) `gist` and check if you have missed anything. especially `Create mongo.ini file in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available` section @moplin

Comment: **php -v:** PHP 7.1.15-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 (cli), **xampp:** PHP Versión 7.1.16, yes I do have the mongodb.ini «inside I can see the extension=mongodb.so uncommented» on the path you mentioned. the only thing that I guess can be a problem is the difference on versions on php.

Comment: @moplin did you used brew or pecl for installation ?

Comment: Initially I used sudo apt-get install php-mongodb, din't work, then I used pecl. 
The file is there, and the php.ini (xampp) has the proper configuration, I can see other extensions like xdebug on, but this one is not loading.